# How can I use Visual Studio performance profiler with a non-localhost IIS URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, profiling

I am trying to profile code (measure function call counts and timing) but the built in profiler is not allowing me to pass in my URL when I tell it I'm profiling.

My steps

1. Analyze > Performance Profiler
2. Target = ASP.NET
3. Select "Performance Wizard" and hit Start
4. Wizard pops up, select Instrumentation, Next
5. Select "An ASP.Net application" for instrumentation method
6. Next screen asks "what URL or path will run your web application" and I type in: https://something.mydomain.com/some/url/here

I use a hosts file and SSL certificate locally so I can make sure those features work properly. Unfortunately it seems the performance wizard doesn't allow this unless your URL is "localhost". Is there a way around this silliness?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't believe it won't use a loopback domain. Have you figured out a way around this?

Comment: @DonnyV. I think I gave up. I don't remember finding a way around it